# NSDataDetection for Dates in Images with different Formats dependent of Locale?

Tags: swift, foundation

I would like to convert a **Date on an image to a Date type in Swift** to store that data. I thought that I could use **NSDataDetector** for doing this, because I don't know the exact format which will occur on the image.

I had for example this Date: **01.08.2022** with the format: **dd.mm.yyyy** but if I use the NSDataDetector it was interpreted with the format **mm.dd.yyyy**

Is it possible to change that behavior so that the **usual order** of the numbers for the days and months **for the region** is used for interpretation?

Thanks for an answer

Comment: If you want to find the date format used by the locale, then `DateFormatter` has a `.locale` property you can set. Refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter

Comment: Is this then used by the detector?

Comment: Quoted from `NSDataDetector` documentation, "You should only use NSDataDetector on natural language text. If text is expected to be in a particular format, you should instead use a Formatter or ValueTransformer subclass. For instance, if you are expecting a date field to be represented by an ISO 8601 timestamp, you should use DateFormatter to parse that into an NSDate object." Refer - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatadetector

Comment: But I don’t know the exact format, I wanna search for a date on the image to store it, is there an alternative to transform the string to a date without knowing the exact format?

Comment: Well if you don't know the exact format, you could use a bunch of `if else` statements, starting with `locale` currently used, then check for the formats that you think are common. As far as I know, there is no straight forward way get it directly

Comment: Ok thanks. I thought this would be something like that, but then I try to do it myself

Comment: If you have shortlist of known formats, you can try matching a regex to determine the format string. If they're human-entered, this will make bad dates inevitable (many Americans use `-` and `/` without realizing they imply different formats, for example). Use EXIF if available, check down to known formats, then have a plan if the date can't be accurately guessed. Or just live with dates that aren't always accurate to the facts.

Comment: The date would be printed on paper so the problem should be to get the numbers separated correctly and having the right format.